# Invoke-Command - use predefined function and object

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, invoke-command

i want to use a predefined function on a remote server with ps invoke and i need to send an object as parameter. This code always writes objects first element.

```
$object = @('a','b','c')

function testA {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.Object]
        $test
    )

    write-host $test
    
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:testA} -ArgumentList $object
```

Is there a way to pass function and object to the remote server with Invoke-Command?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **pass the *array* stored in `$object` *as a single argument* and it is the *only* argument to pass**, you need to **wrap it in a *transient single-element wrapper array* when you pass it to `-ArgumentList`** - otherwise, the array elements are passed as *individual* arguments:

```bash
# Alias -Args for -ArgumentList is used for brevity.
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:testA} -Args (, $object)
```

`, $object` uses the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), to construct a single-element array whose only element is the `$object` array. `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) then enumerates the elements of this transient array to form the individual arguments, and therefore passes the one and only element - which is the `$object` array - as-is.

Note that the problem only arises because you want to pass only a *single* argument; with two or more arguments, use of the *binary* form of `,` is needed anyway, which unambiguously makes `$object` as a whole its own argument; e.g., `... -ArgumentList $object, 'foo'`